# Customize validation message of ice:selectInputDate

Tags: jsf, icefaces

I am using selectInputDate component on a JSF Icefaces form as below.

```
<ice:selectInputDate id="toDateId"
                renderMonthAsDropdown="true" renderYearAsDropdown="true"
                value="#{myBackingBean.toRequestDate}" 
                onkeydown="checkDateMaxLen('myform:toDateId', 'Request To Date');searchOnEnterKeyPress(event)"  
                renderAsPopup="true">
                <f:convertDateTime timeZone="#{dateSelectBB.timeZone}"
                    dateStyle="short" />
                <h:outputText value="(mm/dd/yy)" />
            </ice:selectInputDate>
```

When I enter an invalid date e.g. "sdsdsds" and tab off to another field I get the error as 'myform:toDateId: 'sdsdsds' is an invalid date. '

How do I remove form and field id names from the message and show the error as below?

'sdsdsds' is an invalid date.

Implementation details: JSF 2.0, Icefaces 2.0.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put in your message bundle (messages.properties) something like this:

```
javax.faces.converter.DateTimeConverter.DATE_detail=Invalid date format.
```

to overwrite the JSF error messages.

More details you can see here: http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/customize-validation-error-message-in-jsf-2-0/

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: Thanks. I added _detail to my message bundle but I was still seeing error. May I am not overwriting the message detail in my code; will look into it.

Comment: Thanks. I added _detail to my message bundle but I was still getting DATE message instead of DATE_detail. May be I am not overwriting the message detail in my code; will look into it though. My requirement was to get label name and field name from jsf form and update them into place holders in custom validation message. I was able to accomplish it by changing the validation message in message bundle to "The {2} ''{0}'' is invalid. A valid date format is mm/dd/yy. "    and adding label="begin date' to the selectInputDate component in JSF.

Comment: I did the same thing with f:validateLength and I've overwrite the JSF error which contained the form id with my own error using the message bundle like this: "javax.faces.validator.LengthValidator.MINIMUM=Min length required is ''{0}''" and 0 means the minimum value set in the f:validateLength tag. I'm sure you will find anything you need in that link. If you still need help please let me know with more details! Hope this helps :)

Comment: I should have added this also in the answer:"javax.faces.converter.DateTimeConverter.DATE={2}: ''{0}'' could not be understood as a date." But like I sad earlier, in that link you find a very good example. If this answer helped you solve the issue, mark it as the answer to your issue so it will help other s when they have the same issue! ;) Thanks